# adding page control to Data Tables but when code run nothing appear in page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, datatables

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function () {
                 $('#example').dataTable({
                     "pagingType": "full_numbers"
                 });
             });
```

the page control in data table not appear and when am running the code it's run without error but no page control in data table

Comment: Why are you loading jquery-1.7.1 and jquery-1.3.2.min.js and then another file earlier called jquery.js? That could be your issue. Check console and see if any errors are popping up.

Comment: load jquery only from google cdn ... also try to use only one JS file ! Because you will have performance issues(your site will load slower) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres an example http://jsfiddle.net/w94jaras/

Its off the jquery Datatables documentation. I believe you were trying the same thing. Your issue is you are loading usless js files and in the wrong order.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.js"/>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
                 $(document).ready(function () {
                     $('#example').dataTable({
                         "pagingType": "full_numbers"
                     });
                 });
</script>
```

You also have to include the Jquery datatable css file as well.